Solidify modifier causing volume loss in self-intersecting mesh
I'm encountering issues with the Solidify modifier on a self-intersecting mesh.
The mesh is generated from a curve that's been screwed around an axis. As shown in the first image, the curve crosses itself.

I then add a Solidify modifier to the mesh and apply a volumetric shader.
The result, as seen in the second image, lacks volume where the mesh self-intersects. My impression is that there's no "inner volume" in that part.

Is there any way to avoid this lack of volume in the intersecting region? Note how on the overlapping region there is no emission and there is a thin line of nothing.
I'm aiming to use the Principled Volume shader in this case because I want to emit light from a very thin mesh. I don't want to use a surface shader.
